# how to put check on battery level in android studio

Tags: android, batterylevel

I have never done anything related to battery. So, I am totally new to it. I have a broadcast in my application through which I receive and send msgs and perform particular tasks .Now one of my task is to check that if the battery level is below 20% or 15% , do some task. I don't know how to put that check :( in my broadcast file. Thanks for help in advance:).

Updating my Question:
Till now I have done this so far

```
public class BatteryBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

DatabaseHelper db;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    db = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    String cont1 = db.usercontact().toString();

    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action != null && action.equals(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED)) {

        int level = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL,-1);
        int scale = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE,-1);
        int percentage = level * 100 / scale;

        if(percentage <=  20){
           // doing something like getting location
        }
    }
}
```

I have registered my broadcast in activity:

```
public class Battery extends AppCompatActivity {

private BatteryBroadcastReceiver batteryReceiver = new BatteryBroadcastReceiver();
private IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_auto_location);


}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    registerReceiver(batteryReceiver,intentFilter);
}

@Override
protected void onPause(){
    unregisterReceiver(batteryReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}
```

}

This general piece of code is working fine but it is restricting me to just this activity (may be because broadcast is registered in this activity). Like as long as this activity remains open I can perform some task but as I closes it, when battery gets low it perform no task. Now I don't know what to do. I have other activities too in my application and I want it to work even when I am not on this activity. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Look into this documentation for some information:
https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring

A section in the page that may help you:

"
You can't easily continually monitor the battery state, but you don't need to.

Generally speaking, the impact of constantly monitoring the battery level has a greater impact on the battery than your app's normal behavior, so it's good practice to only monitor significant changes in battery level—specifically when the device enters or exits a low battery state.

The manifest snippet below is extracted from the intent filter element within a broadcast receiver. The receiver is triggered whenever the device battery becomes low or exits the low condition by listening for ACTION_BATTERY_LOW and ACTION_BATTERY_OKAY.

```
<receiver android:name=".BatteryLevelReceiver">
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW"/>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_BATTERY_OKAY"/>
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

"

Update:
Try using the following code in your broadcast file:

```java
int level = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);
int scale = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);

float batteryPct = level / (float)scale;
```

Comment: This is what I can do in my manifest. But I have seen many videos related to battery level and all they do is to register broadcast in code not in manifest.I have tried what you have told but didn't work until I register it in code. Is there any way that I can do this without registering it in code because that restricts me to specific activity which I don't want.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Sorry for the very late response, and I hope this solves your question!